# Option Clash for Hyperref Package with the Report Document Class

Tags: hyperref, report, option-clash

I know `hyperref` is a problematic package and there are many discussion on how to avoid potential problems.

However, in this small piece of code, I am not event loading any package, and yet, I get the option clash error for the `hyperref` package.

Can someone please help me figure out what the problem is? If I can get this one to work, I will try my main document with many packages!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter one}
Figure \ref{fig1} shows ...

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE HERE!
\caption{caption for figure one}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I work in TexMaker and use PDFLatex to compile! Any idea why I am getting this error?!

Comment: I am copying this from my log file: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2012.10.11)

Comment: the actual version is Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.2.25). You should update ...

Comment: @Salman Try deleting the auxiliary files and compiling again.

Comment: Please read the answers to [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) Especially: “Minimal” means remove all packages, that do not influence output or error, _but leave in all_, that have an influence. In many cases one finds the rising cause oneself.

Comment: @doncherry thank you! I got rid of the auxiliary files and they error went away!

Answer (score 5):

The option clash error requires that the same package is loaded twice. The second time with at least one new option that was not given at the time, when the package was loaded first (LaTeX loads a package the first time, at subsequent loading requests it only checks the options).

Only one package is specified by the example file, thus the second load request has to be in an automatically loaded configuration file. Since option `colorlinks`  is not given, the only configuration file is `hyperref.cfg`. Perhaps you are
using `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}` there to set some options. That's pointless,
LaTeX does not load the package twice. Use `\hypersetup` instead.